# Angular two forms, two ng-click, same function, only the first one runs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I have two forms on a page. The first adds an item to the database, and the second is prepopulated with the data and allows the user to modify the item. The first form allows the user to create and remove sub-items dynamically...

```
<div class="clonableSubItem__inputContainer" ng-repeat="name in item.sub_items track by $index">
    <input type="text" class="form__textInput__field subItem" ng-model="item.sub_items[$index]">
    <input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last">
    <input type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event, $index)" value="Delete" ng-show="$index != 0">
</div>
```

...and the angular

```
$scope.item.sub_items = [""];
    $scope.addRow = function(index) {
        var name = "";
        if($scope.item.sub_items.length <= index+1) {
            $scope.item.sub_items.splice(index+1, 0, name);
        }
    };

$scope.deleteRow = function(event, index) {
    if(event.which == 1) {
        $scope.item.sub_items.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

The second form looks nearly identical...

```
<li ng-repeat="name in item.sub_items track by $index">
    <input class="subItem" type="text" ng-init="name=name" value="{[{ name }]}" ng-model="item.sub_items[$index]">
    <input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last">
    <input type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event, $index)" value="Delete" ng-show="$index != 0">
</li>
```

I thought I could use the same functions for adding and removing the pre-populated sub_items, but clicking these buttons only adds and removes sub_items from the first form. In jQuery I would use "this" inside an .each() more than likely. Here it seems like there is a conflict between the scopes. How can I reuse these functions, but have it operate on the correct item?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. In plunker it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/vmOieFIoGf1p5RTdrH4t?p=preview

Comment: I didn't clarify in my question, but the item in the first form starts out empty. When the form is submitted, it writes to the database. I have another function that fetches all the items and pre-populates values into the second form for each item. The problem is that the add and delete for these sub_items is not altering the item that has the prepopulated values, but the empty form that added the item in the first place.